# If $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere, then $\tilde{f}=f$ almost everywhere, where $\tilde{f}:=\limsup_{n \to \infty} f_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Question:** If $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere, then $\tilde{f}=f$ almost everywhere, where $\tilde{f}:=\limsup_{n \to \infty} f_n$.

**My try:** Since $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere, so there exists a measurable set $E \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\mu(E)=0$ and $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for every $x \in E^c$, i.e., $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$.

The goal is to show that $\displaystyle \limsup_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)=f(x)$ for every $x \in E^c$, but I don't see how?

Comment: If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists then it is equal to $\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n$. Indeed one definition of $\lim$ is to be equal to both $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ when those matches.

Comment: @P.Quinton Ok, but then why is it the case that $\tilde{f}=f$ almost everywhere?

Comment: For every $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $f_n(\omega)\to f(\omega)$,  we also have that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} f_n(\omega)=f(\omega)=\tilde f(\omega)$. I think you can conclude by your argument on the set $E$ now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the set $\{x: f_n(x) \to f(x)\}$. Then we have $\mu(A^c)=0$ and
clearly $$A \subseteq \{x: f(x) = \tilde{f}(x)\}$$
since for a convergent sequence the limit and the limsup coincide. It follows that
$$\mu\{x: f(x) \ne \tilde{f}(x)\} \leq \mu(A^c) = 0$$ which means that $f= \tilde{f}$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

At first there is no necessity for $E$ to be the measure zero set candidate for $\tilde{f}=f$ too. It can be any other one, of course in most cases they are related by inclusion, although in this case $E$ itself works.

But for proof as @P.Quinton said, since having $\lim$ implies we have equal $\limsup$ as well, so on $E^c$ we have, $\tilde{f} = f$:

$$f_n \overset{E^c}{\longrightarrow} f \Longrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x) \overset{E^c}{==} f(x) \Longrightarrow \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n \overset{E^c}{==} f \Longrightarrow \tilde{f} \overset{E^c}{==} f$$

In fact there is a measure zero set $G \subseteq E$ that satisfis $\tilde{f} \overset{G^c}{==} f$.